# Alguém pode me explicar o significado do símbolo de dólar $ em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Os códigos em questão são os que seguem:

```js
var $item = $(this).parent().parent().find('input');
```

qual a utilidade desse `$` no primeiro código, se eu remove-lo que diferença vai fazer?

```js
function doHomework(subject) {
  alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
}
```

ao que o `$` está se referindo nesse caso? o que precisa estar definido como subject para que faça sentido utiliza-lo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $item = $(this).parent().parent().find('input');
```

Esse é um código em `jQuery`. `$` é um nome de variável válida, e a biblioteca jQuery por padrão define uma variável com o nome `$` como alias para `jQuery`, em outras palavras, `$(this)` é apenas uma forma mais breve de escrever `jQuery(this)`

Por outro lado, em `$item`, o cifrão serve apenas como um indicador, para deixar claro que aquela variável está armazenando um objeto retornado pelo jQuery. Se você remover o cifão dessa variável, o código funcionaria da mesma forma.

```
`Starting my ${subject} homework.`
```

Já nessa linha de código o cirão tem um significado totalmente diferente. Strings delimitadas com tiques podem embutir variáveis que são definidas dentro da marcação `${}`, em outras palavras

```
`Starting my ${subject} homework.`
```

É apenas uma forma alternativa de escrever

```
"Starting my " + subject + " homework."
```

Se você remover o cifrão dessa string, a variável `subject` não seria embutida nessa string, e ao invés de gerar uma string como `Starting my arithmetic homework.` por exemplo, você simplesmente iria gerar `Starting my {subject} homework.`

Answer (score 3):

Tem 3 casos diferentes aí!

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('input');
```

Nesta caso `$` é simplesmente um nome de variável. Não há nenhum significado especial!

Quando você inclui a biblioteca `jquery` no contexto da sua página (adicionando a sua tag  no HTML), esta biblioteca expõe as suas funcionalidades definindo as **variáveis globais** `jQuery` e `$`. Literalmente em algum lugar do código do jquery vai estar escrito `$ = { ... }`.

```
var $item
```

Este daqui é mais uma convenção de boas práticas. Quando uma variável possuir um "objeto do tipo jquery", é convenção a nomear com $ antes. Isso está presente em guias de estilo famosos como o [airbnb style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#jquery)

```
alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
// é o mesmo que
alert("Starting my " + subject + " homework.");
```

Este daqui realmente é uma sintaxe especial do javascript chamado [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Quando você define uma string com aspas inversas ` ao invés de aspas simples ou aspas duplas, ao usar o ${} ele vai **interpolar** uma variável dentro dessa string. É como se fosse um `<?= >` do PHP, só que pra JS.